# pythonのpropertyの変数のアンダースコアの意味

Tags: python

Pythonのpropertyについて質問です。
よく見かけるコードでは以下のようにインスタンス変数の前にアンダースコアがついていますが、
これはどういう意味なのでしょうか？
propertyを使うときには必要なのですか？

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self._x = x
        do_something()
```

Answer (score 4):

名前がアンダースコアで始まる場合、そのインスタンス変数は慣習的にプライベート変数として扱われます。ただし本当のプライベート変数ではないので外側からアクセスすることが出来ます。

[9. クラス — Python 3.6.1 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)

挙げられたコードの場合は、`_x`の代わりに名前`x`でアクセスできるようにゲッタとセッタが定義されていますね。ただ、特にアンダースコアが必要ということは無いはずです。

[2. 組み込み関数 — Python 3.6.1 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/functions.html#property)

Answer (score 3):

名前の一番最初を1つのアンダースコアにするのは、「この変数はクラスの外側には公開されていない」ということを意味するための慣習的な名付けです。

このことはたとえば [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) に次のように書かれています。

> `_single_leading_underscore`: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. `from M import *` does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.

次の投稿も参考になります： ["What is the meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1301346/5989200) -- Stack Overflow